# Convert dataframe to list for Farrington algorithm algo.farrington

Tags: r, surveillance

I have the following example data frame:

```
data.frame(WEEK=c(1:10),YEAR=2000,
           NUMBER=c(0,1,4,25,9,7,4,2,9,12))

   WEEK YEAR NUMBER
1     1 2000      0
2     2 2000      1
3     3 2000      4
4     4 2000     25
5     5 2000      9
6     6 2000      7
7     7 2000      4
8     8 2000      2
9     9 2000      9
10   10 2000     12
```

I want to use the Farrington algorithm `algo.farrington` from the `surveillance` package in R. However, in order to do so my data have to be an object of class disProgObj. Based on the example I found in the PDF of the surveillance package the result should be a list.

Does anyone know how to convert my data so I can get the algorithm to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle such data, the R package surveillance provides the S4 class "sts" (surveillance time series), which supersedes the "disProg" class. To convert your data to an "sts" object:

```
x <- data.frame(WEEK=c(1:10), YEAR=2000, NUMBER=c(0,1,4,25,9,7,4,2,9,12))
xsts <- sts(observed = x$NUMBER, start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 52)
xsts
```

which yields:

```
-- An object of class sts -- 
freq:        52 
start:       2000 1 
dim(observed):   10 1 

Head of observed:
     observed1
[1,]         0
```

This "sts" object could be converted to the obsolete "disProg" class via `sts2disProg()` as illustrated in Roman's answer. However, this conversion is not necessary since the function `farrington()` can be used directly with an "sts" object (it internally calls `algo.farrington()`).

The package authors encourage the use of the newer "sts" class to encapsulate count time series. See the package `vignette("monitoringCounts")` published at http://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v070.i10 for a description of the outbreak detection tools.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(surveillance)

x <- data.frame(WEEK=c(1:10),YEAR=2000,
                NUMBER=c(0,1,4,25,9,7,4,2,9,12))

xsts <- sts(observed = x$NUMBER, start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 52)

sts2disProg(sts = xsts)
```

The above conversion results in a "disProg" object, which prints as follows:

```
-- An object of class disProg -- 
freq:        52 
start:       2000 1 
dim(observed):   10 1 

Head of observed:
     observed1
[1,]         0
```

Comment: This seems to work, but when I try to use algo.farrington(xsts) I get the error: Error in disProgObj$observed : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Comment: @Joep_S you need to save the result of the `stsdisProg` function to a variable and use that in `algo.farrington`.